# Asynchronous AJAX return after page loads

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC and I need to make an asynchronous call to the server only once when the JSP page has loaded completely.

What I actually have is a Controller that returns a List. I call the Controller using AJAX. The problem with my solution is that I'm not able to get the data of List after load JSP page.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/myList")
public ModelAndView getSubView(Model model) 
{
  model.addAttribute("list", userServiceI.getAllUsers());
  return new ModelAndView( "myList" );
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ajaxPost() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "myList",
      success: function(list) {
        alert(list.get(0).name);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Is there any way to return a List After page loaded or how to load asynchronously? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you calling `ajaxPost()` from? If you call it on `document.ready` or `window.load` what you require will work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return List of User instead of ModelAndView and give annotation on List object @ResponseBody. User should be Serializable and you can call ajax function either on wiondwos.onload or document.ready it will load list asynchronously .Do not return ModelAndAiew, it is used for redirecting on page in case of form submit.

Answer (score 1):

```
You need to return Json you can try it as follows 

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/myList")
public String getSubView(Model model) 
{
   JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
   return json.put("list", userServiceI.getAllUsers());  
}

or you can use @ResponseBody as 

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/myList")
@ResponseBody
public ArrayList getSubView(Model model) 
{
  return userServiceI.getAllUsers();
}
```